# How to install libtcod on Arch Linux distro?

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, libraries, pacman

I can't find any documentation on this, other than using `apk-get`. Is there any way to download this library through pacman? I've only been using the linux terminal for maybe a month, so there might be something I'm not getting.

Edit: I'm trying to install the C++ libtcod library.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you need to use the [Arch User Repository](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository) (AUR). Follow the instructions in the Arch Wiki (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository) and then you can install it with your favorite AUR client. For example:

```
$ trizen -Ss libtcod
aur/libtcod 1.15.1-1 [unmaintained] [28+] [0.00%] [22 May 2020]
    Roguelike graphics/utility library
aur/libtcod-151 1.5.1-2 [unmaintained] [9+] [0.00%] [6 Apr 2017]
    Roguelike graphics/utility library (v1.5.1 maintained for brogue)
aur/libtcod-git 1.16.0.alpha.12.r0.g1c8be39-1 [0+] [0.00%] [27 Aug 2020]
    Roguelike graphics/utility library. Development version.
aur/python-libtcod 1.15.1-2 [2+] [0.00%] [8 Jul 2020]
    Python Roguelike graphics/utility library.
aur/python-libtcod-cffi 1.0-1 [unmaintained] [2+] [0.00%] [3 Oct 2016]
    Python CFFI port of libtcod.
aur/python-tdl 1.5.3-4 [out-of-date] [unmaintained] [1+] [0.00%] [4 Aug 2016]
    Pythonic CFFI port of libtcod.
```

So, to install I would then run `trizen -S python-libtcod` or `trizen -S libtcod-git` depending on which one you need.

Comment: Should have mentioned I was getting the libtcod library for c++. Would it be a similar process?

Comment: @Herodegon the `python-libtcod` package is probably the one you want (or the `libtcod-git` one if you want the development files). The `python` bit was added to the name because the older package `libtcod` which is no longer maintained required python bindings to be correctly installed. See the comments at https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/libtcod/

Comment: I see. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Herodegon you're very welcome. Please note that everything I know about this library and package comes from reading those comments, I don't have any experience with the library or with installing it. Also, if this (or any other answer) answers your question,  please take a moment and [accept it](//unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.